# How do you use a cdn to host jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cdn

I have always used the jQuery file to use jquery. Recently I have heard about using a CDN. I wanted to ask how you use it, and what this line of code does:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A content delivery network [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) refers to a geographically distributed group of servers that work together to provide fast delivery of Internet content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<button>Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean any CDN or hosting yourself?
Google has a CDN for jquery (found here https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful to you: https://code.jquery.com/

Select the jQuery version that you want (I prefer jQuery3.x minified).

When you select the jQuery version (also with options), you may copy scripts like

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Insert script in html `<head>`:

```
...
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
...
```